# Random forest in sklearn - predicting in batches vs. predicting one by one

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

Assume that I have a numpy array `X` of 10000 observations and a random forest model `model`. I've noticed that when I use `model.predict(X)` it takes several orders of magnitude less than predicting line by line, i.e.,

```
for i in range(X.shape[0]):
     clf.predict(X[i:i+1,:])
```

In my application I have to do prediction line by line. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: A rule of thumb is to avoid Python loops if you want performance. Why do you have to do predict in a loop?

Comment: @kazemakase: I simulate online settings. I think that the problem isn't iterating over the array, but the prediction itself.

Comment: Your description points at the loop as the cause of the performance difference. Can you explain what makes you think otherwise?

Comment: @kazemakase: Reading the array one by line is fast (I measured), putting each line into the model makes the difference.

Comment: Ah, we were probably talking about the same thing :) I did not mean to imply that the loop itself is slow, but calling `predict` repeatedly is. The `predict` function causes considerable overhead each time it is called, which makes predicting a batch preferable ( that is a typical situation in Python). I don't think it is possible to make it both fast and line-by-line.

Comment: Have you considered to make the online simulation more abstract? You could probably *implement* it using batches, but as far as the data is concerned make it *behave* like it worked one-by-one. (I know, this sounds vague.)

Comment: @kazemakase. Thanks, I understand what you meant but I was hoping I'm doing something wrong so I could avoid it.

Comment: @Roy Can you post the code that defines your model `clf`? Most of the classes in scikit-learn that support a `predict` function automatically support vectorized calls to `predict` across multiple inputs at prediction time. Have you tried directly calling `clf.predict(X[:100, :])` for example to see if makes a batch prediction across those 100 inputs? You say, "In my application I have to do prediction line by line." but I think we need more info about this and about your underlying model.

Comment: I have experienced something similar - particularly for RandomForestRegression. Other regressors, like linear regression, SVR, etc. are much faster in one by one predictions for me. Any clue where this comes from?